# Python Matplotlib meshes contourplot wrong

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm using python3 with numpy, scipy and matplotlib and want to plot a simple contourf-plot where the plot-grid is not equidistant. mlab.girddata unfortunatelly seems only to work with one-dimensional input, but that's not what I need. I have the following grid-(arrays) for the coordinates:

[image]
[image]
Though the first coordinate-array is uniform, as you can see the second one is not. And since not even the columns are the same, I cannot use mlab.griddata :/

Eventually, the following data array should be plotted versus the showed coordinates:
[image]

How can I plot this correctly? Without a uniform grid matplotlib unfortunatelly just plots a useless picture:

[image]

Here the code:

```
coordsForPlot = np.transpose(np.tile(self.CoordsVert_HW12[1:], (15, 1)));
figHandler = plt.figure();

cont_HW_u12_mean = plt.contourf(self.CoordsHor, coordsForPlot, self.velHW_Raw_u12_mean, 40, linestyle=None);
```

Thanks,

itpdg

Comment: Matplotlib behavior seems correct to me. It's assuming you gave a logical sorted sequence to your data so cell 2 will appear after cell 1. If not it still plots but with the deformation you imposed. You need to take your X, and Y, flatten them (also Z), and use them to interpolate into a regular grid, for example. Than you can plot your result. Consider providing your data to get an actual working example.

Comment: I'd start by fixing the order in every other x-column (by flipping it and the corresponding  rows in z).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is scattered, you can either use some triangulation (such as [`matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf), or interpolate your data on a regular grid (as also suggested by @armatita [almost a month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089964/python-matplotlib-meshes-contourplot-wrong#comment61729996_37089964)). I'm going to show you the latter.

But first: please read @armatita's previously mentioned comment very well. Here it is, for posterity:

> Matplotlib behavior seems correct to me. It's assuming you gave a
>   logical sorted sequence to your data so cell 2 will appear after cell
>   1. If not it still plots but with the deformation you imposed. You need to take your X, and Y, flatten them (also Z), and use them to
>   interpolate into a regular grid, for example. Than you can plot your
>   result. Consider providing your data to get an actual working example.

Firstly, there's the basic idea of the answer. Secondly, you were explicitly asked to provide some sample data. This helps a lot for answerers who want to help you, and this also helps *you* by helping askers. I was bored so I took my time and copied an approximation of a bit of your data to come up with an example. However, this is tedious, and most answerers won't bother doing this for you (and I won't be doing this for anybody else in the near future). Please understand that by providing a minimal, complete example (also known as an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) you make your question fully answerable. Everybody wins.

So here goes. Without your actual data I can't tell if the result makes sense. The idea is to create a regular mesh, then use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to obtain an interpolated data set that can later be fed into `contourf`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# create weird dummy data
xmat = np.tile(np.arange(90,640,90)[:,None],[1,4])
ymat = np.array([[-70.,80,-70,60,-50,50,-50],
                 [-49,64,-49,48,-34,41,-34],
                 [-30,49,-30,38,-20,32,-20],
                 [-13,36,-13,28,-7,25,-7]]).T
zmat = np.tile(np.array([7.5,9,11,12,13,14,14])[:,None],[1,4])

# input data for griddata
points_in = np.array([xmat.ravel(),ymat.ravel()]).T
values = zmat.ravel()

# output mesh at which to interpolate
Ngrid = 50
xvals = np.linspace(xmat.min(),xmat.max(),Ngrid)
yvals = np.linspace(ymat.min(),ymat.max(),Ngrid)
xplot,yplot = np.meshgrid(xvals,yvals)

# interpolate
zplot = interp.griddata(points_in,values,(xplot,yplot),method='linear')

# plot
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(xplot,yplot,zplot,N=50)
plt.show()
```